# Sort an array of object with key in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I am trying to sort the array of an objects with key which is date which looks like this

```js
myArray = [{
  '2022-04-01': '0.01'
}, {
  '2022-03-31': '0.02'
}, {
  '2022-04-02': '0.05'
}]
```

But I want to have like this

```
myArray = [{
  '2022-03-31': '0.02'
}, {
  '2022-04-01': '0.01'
}, {
  '2022-04-02': '0.05'
}],
```

I tried diff num of sols, which already there on stackoverflow, but none of them match to my case.

Comment: Next time please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: @mplungjan this will not solve my problem, let me update my problem..

Comment: I meant `myArray.sort((a,b) => Object.keys(a)[0] < Object.keys(b)[0] ? 1 : -1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just this will work.

```
myArray.sort((a,b) => Object.entries(a)[0] < Object.entries(b)[0] ? -1 : 1);
```

Running example below:

```js
const myArray = [
  { '2022-03-31': '32.2'   }, 
  { '2022-04-01': '32.23'  }, 
  { '2022-04-02': '32.9'   }, 
  { '2022-03-30': '32.253' }, 
  { '2022-04-03': '32.253' },
  { '2022-03-18': '32.253' },
  { '2021-06-31': '32.37' }
];

myArray.sort((a,b) => Object.entries(a)[0] < Object.entries(b)[0] ? -1 : 1);

console.log(myArray);
```

You can also use `Object.keys` instead of `Object.entries` like:

```
Object.keys(a)[0]
```